# Specifying the "project name" for Package Manager migration operations

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

I recently restored my Visual Studio solution by cloning from a remote GIT repository. Now, for some mysterious reason, "migration" commands that I enter in the Package Manager Console (e.g. "get-migrations") fail unless I explicitly specify the main project name, e.g.:

```
get-migrations -projectname Indigo
```

If I omit the project name then it looks in a project that isn't the main project, and it complains:

```
PM> get-migrations
Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Indigo.Tests'.
  (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package
  Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).
```

Where is VS getting its concept of the project tied to the database?  How do I teach VS to use the correct project by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the **Package Manager Console**, the default project will automatically be assigned to the name of the startup project in your solution even if this project doesn't contain a EF Context.

[image]

If you can't set the project that contain your EF context as a startup project for your solution then the only choice you have is to manually set the **Default project** dropdown list to the correct project name. By doing that you will not need to specify the name of the project when typing your commands.

Comment: Aha! I didn't notice the "Default project" dropdown list.  A couple of notes on your answer: (1) Fiddling with the "startup" project doesn't magically fix the "default" project.  I tried that before I posted the question.  (2) Somehow, something in VS has now noticed my new "startup" project and set the "default" project to match.  But that didn't happen immediately, or even after I closed and reopened the solution a couple of times.  But now it's correct.  Magic...